# Existe setSelection no TableLayout ou TableRow?

Tags: android

No ListView tem o método `setSelection()` onde você pode selecionar um índice da sua lista para apontar neste índice quando abrir a lista. Por exemplo em um ListView com 100 números, se você colocar `setSelection(34)`, quando abrir a activity do ListView, ficará apontado no valor 34 e não no início da lista. Sempre usei isto com lista, mas agora preciso usar isso em uma TableLayout. Alguém sabe como e se é mesmo possível fazer isso? Agradeço desde já.

obs: Testei pegar o focus mas não deu certo.

Comment: Vc setou o focus como true na linha que vc queria, até ai tudo bem, agora tente setar o focus para false para todos os outros componentes do layout.

Comment: também não funcionou.